# What is more appropriate sp_updatestats or UPDATE STATISTICS?

Tags: sql-server, performance, statistics

In a system there is a nightly data load process where all the foreign keys are dropped, all tables are truncated, repopulated from an external source, and the foreign keys are put back in place.

At the end of this process I would expect  `sp_updatestats` to run, so that statistics for all this new data is updated.

However, while inspecting the code I noticed the following line instead:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'
```

Can you compare that with running `sp_updatestats`? That is what is the differences and advantages/disadvantages of one over the other?

Comment: I'd suggest [not using sp_MSforeachtable](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) in general.

Comment: @JohnM, yep, why?

Comment: That's what the link is for :) It's an undocumented stored procedure that can't always be trusted.

Comment: @JohnM, silly me! Admit, you sneaked up this link in in the last second! ;)

Comment: Just expanded the words the link used to make it more obvious

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple of things ..

1. [Stop using the undocumented](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/) sp_MSforeachtable
2. From Erin's blog - [Understanding What sp_updatestats Really Updates](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-statistics/statistics-updates)

   > sp_updatestats updates only the statistics that require updating based on the rowmodctr information in the sys.sysindexes catalog view, thus avoiding unnecessary updates of statistics on unchanged rows

Note that `sp_updatestats` in the code `sp_helptext sp_updatestats`, it runs `'UPDATE STATISTICS '`

[image]

**Recommendation:**

- Use [Ola's Index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

[image]